# How to get idevicerestore shared object file?

Tags: iphone, linux, ubuntu, ios10, ubuntu-16.04

I am having some linking problem with the `idevicerestore` function. Is there any way to build `idevicerestore` so that I get a shared object file i.e idevicerestore.so?

Comment: are you using libimobiledevice if yes then try using ldconfig when you install libimobiledevice

Comment: i already installed libimobiledevice from [https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice] after then when i install idevicerestore from [https://github.com/libimobiledevice/idevicerestore] it doesnt generate .so file @Narendra Pandey

Comment: everything works fine except when i try to use library functions defined in idevicerestore like ipsw_download_latest_fw... its says undefined refrence to ipsw_download_latest_fw @Narendra Pandey